# Include two multiple when scraping data

Tags: r, web-scraping

Wish to scrape weather data from

https://www.wetterzentrale.de/weatherdata.php?station=260&jaar=2019&maand=1&dag=1

From 2019-01-01 until today, yet I don't know how to write a code that changes jaar=2019 (i.e., year=2019), maand=1 (i.e., month=1) and dag=1 (i.e., day=1) to the desired days.

I tried to work with lapply as:

```
    years <- c("2019", "2020")
    urls <- rbindlist(lapply(years, function(x) {
       url <- paste(https://www.wetterzentrale.de/weatherdata.php?station=260&jaar=2019&maand=1&dag=1, sep = "")
       data.frame(url)
    } ))
```

Hence this only gives the urls for 2019 and 2020. Is there a way to include months and days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(lubridate)

allYourDates <- seq(ymd(20190101), Sys.Date(), by = "days")
urls <- paste("https://www.wetterzentrale.de/weatherdata.php?station=260&jaar=", year(allYourDates)
              , "&maand=", month(allYourDates)
              , "&dag=", day(allYourDates)
              , sep = "")
```